# Calling stored procedure from another stored procedure and returning result as new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to call stored procedure from another stored procedure and return the result as first one's column?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetItems]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT ID, AddedDate, Title,Description,
       Result of Stored Procedure "CountAll" call with parameter ID as Total 
FROM dbo.Table1
```

And also: how to be if CountAll stored procedure returns some columns and not just scalar?

Comment: You may not need a stored procedure for "CountAll" if you tell us what it does.

Comment: Thomas , Count all Counts some entries from another table taking ID as parameter

Comment: Given that, you shouldn't need a sp. If you provide us the details of the CountAll procedures, we can be more specific but in general, there are plenty of means within the SQL syntax to get counts in a single query.

Answer (score 4):

Ouput parameter for one value:

```
EXEC CountAll @Total OUTPUT
SELECT ID, AddedDate, Title,Description,@total as Total
FROM dbo.Table1
```

Or use CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT ID, AddedDate, Title,Description,@total as Total
FROM dbo.Table1
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT soemthing as total FROM .... WHERE...)
```

Or use a UDF

or a derived table

```
SELECT ID, AddedDate, Title,Description, totals.Total
FROM
   dbo.Table1 T
   JOIN
   (SELECT count(*) as Total, id FROM dbo.Table1 GROUP BY ID) totals ON T.ID = totals.id
```

If the stored proc returns multiple columns, then you have to use a udf, cross apply, derived table or return 2 result sets to the client

Basically, stored procs can not be used the way you want

Comment: basically I want to execute CountAll for every row of table1 that is returned to the user

Comment: OK, use CROSS APPLY or a udf or a derived table then

Comment: +1 Definitely doable any of these ways, sounds like a CROSS APPLY with a table-valued UDF is going to be OP's best bet.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, AddedDate, Title,Description,
       , ( Select Count(*)
            From OtherTable
            Where Table1.Id = OtherTable.Id ) As ItemCount
FROM dbo.Table1
```

You shouldn't need a stored procedure to simply get a count of items from another table. You can do it in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need a user defined function UDF instead of procedure. (If I remember well you can not call stored procedure from UDF)

Oher posibilities how to refactor your query are shown in aswer by gbn.